# Recode categorical variable to binary (0/1)

Tags: r, recode

Could someone help me regarding the use of `ifelse`.

I have a `data.frame` (dat) with a categorical variable/factor called Q1 (`dat$Q1`). `dat$Q1` was coded as 1,2,3 or 4. I need to create a new column `data$new1` based on the following rule:

if `dat$Q1 == 3` then `dat$new1` should be `1`. otherwise, `dat$new1` should be `0`.

What is the most efficient way of doing this please?

Answer (score 8):

Use `ifelse` as in:

```
dat$new1 <- ifelse(dat$Q1==3, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!! New to this site but I am very impressed :-)

Answer (score 6):

Just:

```
 dat$new1 <-  0+(dat$Q1==3)  # or use as.numeric(.)
```

Comment: `as.numeric` has the edge using `microbenchmark`.  It seems more idiomatic as well. +1

Comment: Agreed, and if the goal were to have the values be 2 and 1 then use `1+as.numeric(dat$Q1==3)`.